# How can I use C# to script a C# application with variable and class access

Tags: c#, scripting, mono, roslyn, cs-script

I can find a lot of info on using C# as a scripting language (CSScript, Mono, Roslyn), but none of it seems to do what I need (or it does and I simply don't understand how to use it).

What I want to be able to do is this: Let's say I write a C# program with several classes. When the program starts it either looks for a cs file or a script in memory. I cut and paste one of the classes from the program either into the file or text box. When the program loads it finds that class and runs EXACTLY as it did before except now the class is in another location. I can edit this class (script) and access the other classes and variables in the program to change parts of the program without compiling.

Is this possible? If not, what is the best solution (cross platform would be good)?

Comment: The `AppDomain.TypeResolve` event may help you.  However, this is unlikely to be easily possible.